# Media keys not working for iTunes high Sierra

Tags: itunes, keyboard, macos, high-sierra

I don't know what's happening but, during the day media keys accidentally start/stop working for manage `iTunes`. 
For me helps only rebootthe whole system.
I've googled for solution but any of it not work for me. 
(there are no any of extensions like `Spotify`, `Deezer` etc on mine).
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that with High Sierra Apple is trying to detect which application should be controlled by the media keys. They work fine until you use something (e.g., a browser other than Safari) and the system get confused.

This can be fixed with an open source application: [BeardedSpice](http://beardedspice.github.io)

> BeardedSpice is a menubar application for Mac OSX that allows you to
>   control web based media players and some native apps with the media
>   keys found on Mac keyboards. It is an extensible application that
>   works with Chrome (Canary, Yandex, Chromium) and Safari, and can
>   control any tab with an applicable media player.